# Exact symbolic area of an intersection of two polygons with parameters

Tags: regions, polygons, computational-geometry

On the one hand, can handle expressions which include parameters, including polygons, for example:

```
Area[Polygon[{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 5}, {1, a}}]]
```

returns

```
1/2 Abs[-7 + a]
```

On the other hand, `RegionIntersection` breaks the symbolic evaluation. Consider a minimal example:

```
Area[
  RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 5}}],
    Polygon[{{2, 4}, {1, -3}, {1, a}}]
  ]
]
```

Clearly, this is equal to some piecewise function of $a$. However, $0$ is returned. How to force Mathematica to give a function of $a$ as a result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having `Area` generate conditions is informative:

```
Area[
  RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 5}}], 
    Polygon[{{2, 4}, {1, -3}, {1, a}}]
  ],
  GenerateConditions -> True
]

(* Out: ConditionalExpression[0, a < 2] *)
```

Indeed, for $a<2$ there is no intersection, so the area of the intersection is correctly $0$.

On the one hand, we can try to feed an assumption to `Area` that $a>2$:

```
Area[
  RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 5}}], 
    Polygon[{{2, 4}, {1, -3}, {1, a}}]
  ],
  Assumptions -> a > 2
]

(* Out: (5*(5 - 11*a + 3*a^2))/(6*(-1 + a)*(-8 + 3*a)) *)
```

That area is now expressed as a function of $a$ as desired.

More generally, we can use `GenerateConditions -> All`:

```
Area[
  RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 5}}], 
    Polygon[{{2, 4}, {1, -3}, {1, a}}]
  ],
  GenerateConditions -> All
]

(* Out:
Piecewise[{
  {(4 - 4*a + a^2)/(2*(-1 + a)),                   2 <= a <= 11/3}, 
  {(5*(5 - 11*a + 3*a^2))/(6*(-1 + a)*(-8 + 3*a)), a > 11/3}},
  0
]
*)
```

[image: 2D graphical representation of the above Piecewise function]

---

This also works for multiple parameters. For the example mentioned in comments of two-parameter triangular regions:

```
Area[
  RegionIntersection[
    Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {a, b}}],
    Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
  ],
  GenerateConditions -> All
]

(* Out:
Piecewise[{
  {1/2,               a <= 0 && a + b > 1}, 
  {b/2,               0 < a <=1 && b > 0 && a + b <= 1}, 
  {-(b/(2*(-1 + a))), a <= 0 && b > 0 && a + b <= 1}, 
  {b/(2*(a + b)),    (0 < a <= 1 && a + b > 1) || (a > 1 && b > 0)}},
  0
]
*)
```

[image: 2D representation of the Piecewise area for two triangles]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is possible to generalize this method if there are two parameters $a,b$ in the definition of polygons instead of just $a$?

Comment: you could try GenerateConditions -> All

Comment: @MarcoB, for two parameters a,b, and a triangle region, it will show no output.

Comment: @Machinato Take a look at the updated version.

Comment: @halmir That's a great idea!

Comment: @MarcoB Your addendum is truly marvelous, and I greatly appreciate that. However, I have added an example of interest where this does not work (at least for me). The two pentagons overlap was the main problem for me from the start. I must appologise I was not specific from the beginning.

Comment: @Machinato I'd recommend removing the edit from this question and writing a completely new one, since what you showed really is a new problem. Otherwise that would make this question into a "moving target" and that's typically frowned upon. You would want to add a link to this question in your new one, but still make it free-standing, i.e. include all details necessary to solve it in that one, and specify how that one is different from this one.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for suggestion, I feel that the answer in this question can serve for other solving a similar task in the future and it is not frutful to "move the target" right here, I have moved that part into another question found here, very, very briefly commenting on what is different:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236701/exact-symbolic-area-of-an-intersection-of-two-regular-pentagons-with-parameters