# Exact symbolic area of an intersection of two regular pentagons with parameters

Tags: regions, polygons, computational-geometry

The question of finding the area of intwrsection of two regions with parameters has been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/236510/75682) using and `RegionIntersection` with delimeter `GenerateConditions -> All`. More sophisticated example, for which Mathematica does not return any answer, is as follows.

Consider a vertices of a regular pentagon

```
regulPen[i_] := {Cos[-((2 \[Pi])/5) + (2 \[Pi])/5 i], Sin[-((2 \[Pi])/5) + (2 \[Pi])/5 i]};
```

We now rotate this pentagon by $\pi/5$, forming a new pentagon with vertices

```
regulPenShif[i_] := {Cos[-(\[Pi]/5) + (2 \[Pi])/5 i], Sin[-(\[Pi]/5) + (2 \[Pi])/5 i]};
```

The area of intersection of these pentagons is $\frac12 \sqrt{\frac52(5+\sqrt{5})}$, which is confirmed by Mathematica. Now we shift the center of the second pentagon into the point $\{p,q\}$, the area of intersection should now depend on $\{p,q\}$, however

```
Area[RegionIntersection[
  Polygon[{regulPen[1],
           regulPen[2],
           regulPen[3],
           regulPen[4],
           regulPen[5]}],
  Polygon[{regulPenShif[1] + {p, q},
           regulPenShif[2] + {p, q},
           regulPenShif[3] + {p, q},
           regulPenShif[4] + {p, q},
           regulPenShif[5] + {p, q}}]],
  GenerateConditions -> All]
```

returns itself. How to refine the code such that Mathematica will solve that indeed?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get an exact symbolic area of the intersection of two regular pentagons with parameters when the parameters are symbolic because `Area` is a computational function like `NIntegrate` and not symbolic expression manipulator like `Integrate`. Even the result you show isn't symbolic; it is just exact.

The best we can do is define a numeric evaluator for the area of the  intersection. Like so:

```
regulPen[i_] := {Cos[-((2 π)/5) + (2 π)/5 i], Sin[-((2 π)/5) + (2 π)/5 i]}
regulPenShif[i_] := {Cos[-(π/5) + (2 π)/5 i], Sin[-(π/5) + (2 π)/5 i]}
area[{p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ}] :=
With[
  {poly =
     Polygon[{regulPen[1], regulPen[2], regulPen[3], regulPen[4], regulPen[5]}]},
  area[{p_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ}] :=
    N @ 
      Area[
        RegionIntersection[
          poly,
          Polygon[
           {regulPenShif[1] + {p, q}, regulPenShif[2] + {p, q}, 
            regulPenShif[3] + {p, q}, regulPenShif[4] + {p, q}, 
            regulPenShif[5] + {p, q}}]]]]
```

Then we can make a demonstration allowing us to see one the pentagons shifting around while the area of intersection is computed. Like so:

```
With[
  {poly = 
     Polygon[{regulPen[1], regulPen[2], regulPen[3], regulPen[4], regulPen[5]}],
   spacer = Invisible["mmmmmmmmmmmm"]},
  Manipulate[
    Column[
      {Graphics[
         {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[],
          poly,
          Polygon[
            {regulPenShif[1] + pq, regulPenShif[2] + pq, regulPenShif[3] + pq, 
             regulPenShif[4] + pq, regulPenShif[5] + pq}]},
         ImageSize -> Medium],
       Style[Row[{"Shift: ", pq, "    Area: ", area[pq]}], "SR"]},
       Center],
    {{pq, {0, 0}, Style[Row[{spacer, "Shift "}], 16]}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {.05, .05},
      ImageSize -> {175, 175}},
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom]]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for concrete `p,q` in 12.2, e.g.

```
p = -1/4; q = 1/2; Area[RegionIntersection[Polygon[{regulPen[1], regulPen[2], 
regulPen[3], regulPen[4],regulPen[5]}],Polygon[{regulPenShif[1] + {p, q}, regulPenShif[2] +{p, q}, 
regulPenShif[3] + {p, q}, regulPenShif[4] +{p, q}, regulPenShif[5] + {p, q}}]]]
```

> `1/2 (1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]) ((Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] (-4 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[10]))/( 4 (-5 + Sqrt[5])) + 1/4 (2 - Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) +..`

, but a long output is not very useful.

Comment: But this result isn't a conditions expressed symbolically in terms of p and q, which is what I believe the OP is asking for. It is just an exact result for a particular pair of exact numbers.

Comment: @m_goldberg: As well as yours.